# Doctrine joined inheritance, disable with queryBuilder

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, multiple-inheritance

I have defined an entity as:

```
@ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
```

Which works fine.

When trying to execute a simple query as:

```
    $_builder = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
    $_builder->select('COUNT(us.id)')
             ->from('TbBundle:UserStatus', 'us')
             ->where('us.user = :user')
             ->setParameter('user', $user);

    return $_builder->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
```

Doctrine will produce a query with some unnecessary left joins due to my inheritance architecture. Can I disable it for this query with queryBuilder in any way?

**The goal:**

I want to build count query using query builder but execute it without any inheritance influence so the executed query is as simple as:

```
SELECT COUNT(us.id) FROM table_name us WHERE us.user_id = 34;
```

I could write it using raw sql and get connection from entityManager but that's ugly.

Comment: Writing the DQL within a repository method wouldn't be so ugly. Have a look at [Extra Lazy Associations](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/extra-lazy-associations.html) but [be careful when using it in Twig](https://tideways.io/profiler/blog/5-doctrine-orm-performance-traps-you-should-avoid).

Comment: Remember that the ORM is for objects.  I don't know of any way to suppress the join in this case.  Really would not make much sense.  If you really feel the need to optimize then sql is pretty much your only option.

Comment: @AdamElsodaney somehow your comment doesn't seems to have anything with the question? :P

Cerad all right then... going to write a pure sql.